# Blocking Call In Popen

Tags: ruby

```
pipe = IO.popen('./myblockingprogram')
while line = pipe.gets
  puts "hello world"
end
```

where `myblockingprogram` is some program that blocks until it receives data over the network, and then it prints some text to stdout. Tested running it from bash directly works great.

However, when I run the program above, I never see any "hello world" lines printed to stdout (the console). Am I wrong that popen starts a whole new process... and therefore even though it makes a blocking call it should not prevent the main ruby program from running due to some global interpreter lock?

Is there a better way to structure a program like this, where I want to read text lines output by another program and process the results in some way (there is no terminating condition, it may run forever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure myblockingprogram flushes the output buffer when it writes to stdout.

A simple example myblockingprogram is:

```
#!/bin/ruby
100.times do
    sleep 10
    $stdout.puts "Hello World"
    $stdout.flush
end
```

Without the flush command you don't see any result from the pipe until the subprocess finishes. With the flush command, you will see intermediate results from the subprocess.

Comment: this actually worked.. but I am confused. Without flushing stdout, it would not show the results even after the subprocess was killed. What could cause that?

Comment: Hmmm...you mean killed as in 'kill -9'? Perhaps then the results are never flushed to stdout but discarded. I found that without the flush the results appeared when the 'myblockingprogram' script ended normally. I didn't try killing the script.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to ensure the Ruby side and popen-ed process "cooperate" and don't block each other.  If it takes a long time to run myblockingprogram you may have to use async techniques to prevent prolonged blocking.

Comment: not sure what you mean by block each other -- also, myblockingprogram runs forever until I manually terminate it, and it is in a blocking state most of that time

Comment: A pipe works by connecting the stdout of the spawned process and the stdin of the parent reads from it.  If either gets stuck then it won't work.  You have to design myblockingprogram so that it exits on its own once it has the content your ruby app needs.

Comment: myblockingprogram calls `printf("text\n")` once it receives data, and then goes back to blocking. Could it be a problem with printf getting buffered? It isn't buffered when I run the program directly